# WindowControllers, IBOutlets, and Object oriented programming?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class, nswindowcontroller

I apologize for the the lack of specificity in the subject line but I'm not totally sure how to categorize my question.   It's a high level-ish question but I feel as if people must encounter this all the time, and I'd like to know how they handle this.  I am a relative noob to objective c and object-oriented programming so forgive me if this is completely obvious to alot of you.

Here goes.  I have a cocoa application which creates both the main window and a main app controller in mainMenu.xib.   My myMainAppController object contains another windowController, say mySubWindowController which is initiated from its own separate nib file as below.  Lets say the subWindow has two elements, maybe a NSTextfield and a NSButton.  So...

```
myMainAppController.h
@interface
   @property (strong) MySubWindowContorller *mySubWindowController;
   ........ so forth


MyMainAppController.m
@implementation
 ......
 self.mySubWindowController = [MySubWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:
 @"mySubWindow"];  
 etc...


MySubWindowController.h
@ interface
  IBOutlet (weak) NSTextfield *myTextField;
  IBOutlet (weak) NSButton *myButton;
....
```

So far, so good I think.   Pretty standard stuff, right?    So here's the crux of my question.  Under this structure of my class, how do I get any information or activity that goes on in the subWindow back to my mainAppController and data from mainAppController to subWindow?   I can't seem to make an IBOutlet or IBAction from the textfield/button back to myMainAppController.h so other than using KVO, how will myMainAppController get any info from mySubWindowController?  What if there is an action which is implemented in the subWindow which requires elements of myMainWindowController?   I can't send the action message back to the myMainAppController and mySubWindowController doesn't have access to other elements of its containing class.  I suppose I could declare and define soft pointers of needed elements in myMainAppController to mySubWindowController, but that somehow seems like a breach of "object oriented-ness" and localization.

What do you do in a situation like this when the a main window and subWindow need to coordinate data and logic?  Am I missing something completely obvious due to my inexperience or is this a situation that occurs fairly common?  In the relatively short time I've been working on my app, I've already come across this a few times.  Trying to get a feel for how others deal with this..

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: I think you need research how work the delegates in objective-c:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

Comment: I'm not sure you're doing this the right way. Does your sub window controller handle a view inside the main controller? Then you should add a 'Custom View' to your xib and let IB instantiate the class. Or is it another window? Then you should create a xib for the other window, and let IB instantiate the controller object.

Comment: No, my subWindowController does not handle a view on the main window.  It is a separate window in a nib file of it's own.  I instantiate subWindowController object inside the mainAppController using initWithWindowName.  I suppose I could instantiate subWindowController in the IB along with its window, but then doesn't that basically leave me with 2 window controllers that have no way of accessing each other in any way?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  I figured out the whole custom delegate concept and everything looks so much cleaner now!

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to write your own custom delegates. Hope below code will help you. In this there are two window controllers, Let say AwindowController and BwindowController. If any activity happened on AwindowController then BwindowController will get to know. For example, i have created one button in AwindowController if we clik on that button then BwindowController will get some messages or data that button click on AwindowController. Like that you can send any data or string value whichever you want to send.
**Note:- Custome delegates has been written in BWindowController**

```
#import "sampleDelegate.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "BWindowController.h"

@interface AWindowController : NSWindowController<sampleDelegate>

{
    NSString *text;
}
@property(readwrite,retain)NSString *text;
-(IBAction)doSet:(id)sender;

@end

#import "AWindowController.h"
#import "BWindowController.h"

@interface AWindowController ()

@end

@implementation AWindowController
@synthesize text;


- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

-(NSString*)getDataValue
{
    return @"Button clicked on AWindow";
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

-(NSString*)windowNibName
{
    return @"AWindowController";
}

-(IBAction)doSet:(id)sender
{
    [self setText:[self text]];
    BWindowController *b=[[BWindowController alloc]init];
    b.delegate=self;
    [b showWindow:self];
}
@end

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "sampleDelegate.h"

@protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(NSString *)getDataValue;
@end
@interface BWindowController : NSWindowController<sampleDelegate>
{
    NSString *bTextValue;
    id<sampleDelegate>delegate;
}
@property(readwrite,retain)NSString *bTextValue;
@property(readwrite,assign)id<sampleDelegate>delegate;
@end

#import "BWindowController.h"
@interface BWindowController ()

@end

@implementation BWindowController
@synthesize bTextValue,delegate;
- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}
-(NSString *)getDataValue
{
    return nil;
}
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
   NSString *str= [[self delegate]getDataValue];
    [self setBTextValue:str];
    [super windowDidLoad];

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
}

-(NSString*)windowNibName
{
    return @"BWindowController";
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help.  I figured out the whole custom delegate concept and everything looks so much cleaner now!

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one mainAppController, you should use the singleton pattern. Create a method +getSingleton() to access the singleton instance from anywhere. NSApplication also makes use of the singleton pattern, see +sharedApplication().

A discussion of the singleton pattern in the context of objective-c can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

If for some reason you cannot use the singleton pattern, you need a link from the window back to the mainAppController. To achieve this, uncheck the option in IB to automatically instantiate the subwindow. Instead, implement awakeFromNib in your mainAppController and instantiate the subwindow yourself, passing it the pointer to the mainAppController.